# Why FormData using with fetch API causing my screen to refresh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm sending the file to the backend (written in Express JS) using fetch API with FormData API. My application is working fine. But after clicking on the Send button, my page is getting refreshed, even though I have not used any HTML form element.

I deleted FormData inside of Send button event listener function callback, and page didn't refresh after that. I also deleted fetch api call but keeping the FormData, and then also page didn't refresh. But on using them together, page gets refreshed.

Front End Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Code Analyzer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Insert the Code File here</h1>

     <input type="file" name="myFile" />
        <button class="btn">Send</button>
      </body>
      <script>
        //Get the DOM elments
        const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
        let input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        let formData = new FormData();

        btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          formData.append("myFile", input.files[0]);
          console.log(formData);

          fetch("http://localhost:9000/analyze", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
          })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      </script>
    </html>
```

Back End Code:

```
//Importing Packages
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();

//Configuring Multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

//Middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

//Routes
app.post("/analyze", upload.single("myFile"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  res.json({ Analyzed: "Yes" });
});

//Server Listening
app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on 9000");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a thought - Have you tried adding `type="button"` on `<button class="btn">Send</button>`?

Comment: Thanks @msbarnard. But its already a normal button. I think it won't cause any change in its behaviour.

Comment: @msbarnard. Just for a try. I did add type="button". Nothing changed.

Comment: I would recommend to use a proper `<form>` and listen to its `submit` event, but no idea why your current setup doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Tried with <form> also. Wrapped the input file and button inside <form>. Also tried changing button type as submit. But still the same issue.

Comment: Is the `Location` header set in the response for some reason?

Comment: Code seems to be right. I tried to run the same over my machine. It ran smoothly. Are you running the front end from a dev server ?? I think that's the culprit.  Run the front end without live-server or dev-server, it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Live Server or other auto-reload tools?
If you save an uploaded file to the watched directory, Live Server will detect the change and reload your browser.
You can avoid reloading by stopping the Live Server or by specifying the extension as ignored files.

I faced a similar issue when using `FormData` and initially thought it was due to JavaScript. But it was due to Live Server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using create-react-app and I execute `serve -s build` after create a production repo, when I tried see the problem it's gone. I figure out that is in developer mode that it's happen.